# Apply source transformation to requirejs module before executing

Tags: javascript, requirejs, client-side

I want to know if its is possible to perform a source code transformation on a requirejs module before the module is executed. This should happen on client side!

Let me give you a toy example for clarification:

```
define(["dep1", "dep2"], function moduleFoo(dep1, dep2) {
  var sum = function(a, b) {
    return a plus b;
  }
  return sum;
});
```

Before `moduleFoo` is executed, I want apply a source code transformation like `'plus' -> '+'` to the module code. So, that the executed function looks like this:

```
function(dep1, dep2) {
  var sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The functionality for the source transformation is already given. So my Question is, if it is possible to apply this transformation using requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do what you want *client-side* would be to write a RequireJS [plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) whose [`load` method](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload) would:

1. Transform the source obtained from the server.
2. Call the `onload.fromText` function with the text of the transformed module source.